# How to deal with Twitter API Limits?

Tags: twitter

I have this project that's based on a Twitter Bot. NOT an abusive or spammer bot. Just a robot that will reply with information about my system when it's mentioned.

The thing is: I expect to have about 3000 mentions/hour. Which means I have to send about 3000 replies/hour.

I know Twitter API calls are limited to 350/h when the app is authenticated and 150/h when it's not. But I've also read about it being 1000/h somewhere in the Twitter Discussion boards.

Anyway, how can I deal with having to send so many replies/hour?

I thought about creating multiple Twitter accounts and delegating some of the replies to them in order to being able to reply to all of them, but I do realize it's not a pretty solution.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use [Streaming](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis).

- [Connecting](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/connecting)
- [API Params](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters) (JSON)

Basically, you open up a connection with their server with your credentials and instead of reading the return stream and closing, you just keep reading. When you want to make a request, you just send another header or something.

Comment: Sounds awesome!
And apparently there's not explicit rate limiting, right?

Also, I know it's a bit off-topic but would that work for reading my bot's timeline **all the time** (realtime) to get all the mentions to this account in order to reply to them?

Comment: @BeOliveira there is no limit AFAIK. And no, if the app closes, the stream closes. You can make the streaming part of another app that returns the stuff so when the app opens back up, it reads the other app's data.

Comment: @BeOliveira however, what I would do is on close, just make note of where the were on the timeline and load from them on open. Thats what a lot of twitter clients do

Comment: Interesting! But I won't have a User Interface. I just need to keep verifying my Bot's timeline and replying to whoever mentions it in realtime.

So it's basically a Model-Controller app. There won't be any app closing or re-opening, because there's no app to close. 

Do you think that's possible to pull off?

Comment: Great! Well, apparently my question has been answered. I'll mark your answer as soon as I can get to test it with Streaming, but seems like it'll work as I need it to. Thanks man!